# Best way to manage settings without a file in Java

Tags: java

what do you think would be the best way to manage settings knowing that I have no use for them to be stored in a file.

Is a simple POJO like below with getters and setters enough?

```java
public class Settings {

    private int setting1;
    private boolean setting2;
    private String setting3;

    public Settings() {
        // Some default values in constructor
        setting1 = 12;
        setting2 = false;
        setting3 = "A setting";
    }

    public int getSetting1() {
        return setting1;
    }

    public void setSetting1(int setting1) {
        this.setting1 = setting1;
    }

    public boolean isSetting2() {
        return setting2;
    }

    public void setSetting2(boolean setting2) {
        this.setting2 = setting2;
    }

    public String getSetting3() {
        return setting3;
    }

    public void setSetting3(String setting3) {
        this.setting3 = setting3;
    }
    
}
```

Should I use something more advanced? Like a class that would capture the type of the parameter in question like `Setting<Integer> setting1 = new Setting(12);` ?

I thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Would using `Map<String, String>` help you? That way, you don't have to modify your data class when you add/remove new settings. Alternatively, you can use custom types (making use of polymorphism) as the keys/values to retain type safety.

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_spring_cloud_config_server might help.

Comment: Use a `Properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

Here's an immutable class that does everything you need. No more, no less:

```java
public final class Settings {
  public final int setting1;
  public final boolean setting2;
  public String setting3;

  public Settings(int setting1, boolean setting2, String setting3) {
    this.setting1 = setting1;
    this.setting2 = setting2;
    this.setting3 = setting3;
  }
}
```

If you expect to compare `Settings` objects, then implement `hashCode` and `equals`.

Everything else is just ceremony until you *actually* need it.

---

If you are using Java 14, then save some key-strokes by using *records*:

```java
public record Settings(int setting1, boolean setting2, String setting3) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the job done with your `Setting` class, I don't see any reason why you need to make it complex.

Getters and setters are introduce mutability. Its better you can create this class more immutable fashion. You can achieve this many ways. Here is two ways,

1. **Builder Pattern**
2. **Create a static factory method instead of constructor (Static factory method pattern)**

Comment: The parameters can be changed later and what do you mean by Builder Pattern?

Comment: Builder is a simple creational design pattern. Here some references [REF1](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/java-builder-pattern-bloch) and [REF2](https://www.baeldung.com/creational-design-patterns). You cannot change state of a immutable object (less error prone).

Comment: If parameters are changing you need to create new instance of that object with new parameters (if you use builder).